# kodi-api-inputstream error

Tags: apt, dependencies, kodi

I'm getting an error message when trying to install Inputstream.rtmp.
The installation fails due to kodi-api-inputstream not of the right build range???, but I'm using the latest Kodi update so it should be OK.

```
sudo apt-get install kodi-inputstream-rtmp
[sudo] password for lo:
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done 
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested
an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that 
some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kodi-inputstream-rtmp : Depends: kodi-api-inputstream (>= 3.0.1)
                        Depends: kodi-api input stream (< 3.1.0)
E: Unable to correct problems, you hace held broken packages.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)